# jquery adding table row with commented out html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I want to add a new row to this table. I load html of the row from the server. Returned html has some other commented out html on the top. Because of that comment adding row doesn't work properly. jQuery removes `<tr>` and `<td>` tags and adds plain text from `<td>` elements. Is it a  bug or expected behaviour?

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr><td>old1</td></tr>
    <!-- <abc -->
    <tr><td>old2</td></tr>
</table>
<input id="add" type="button" value="add"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#tbl tr:last").after("<!-- <abc --><tr><td>New</td></tr>");  
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJEWp/2/)

P.S. The issue is because of '<' in the comment. It works ok with normal comments. And it would also work with '<' if the comment was inserted into/from div elements rather than table/tr. What would be your suggestion to fix this issue without removing comment from the html on server-side.

Comment: Is the offending < in the comment always in the same position in the returned data?

Comment: in theory it is but I use that html on the server side as a template so I wouldn't want that modifying the template (moving the comment) affected the behaviour.

Comment: You use comments in any way after you insert them?

Comment: and normal comment is html comment <!--<form> -->

Comment: Don't need to touch the server... in your jquery just replace <!-- < with <!-- before inserting it into the DOM?

Comment: Daniel: no. I just use some jsp tag on the server side template and it generates some html which I don't want. So I put it in html comment.

Comment: Do you need the comment added to the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove comments by using regular expressions. Code(Demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJEWp/3/)):

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var rawHTML = "<!-- <abc --><tr><td>New</td></tr>";
    var HTMLToAdd = rawHTML.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, '');
    $("#tbl tr:last").after(HTMLToAdd);  
});
```

Shorter version:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#tbl tr:last").after("<!-- <abc --><tr><td>New</td></tr>".replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, ''));  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to my comment above - e.g. the below JS works...

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    newRow = '<!-- <abc --><tr><td>New</td></tr>';
    var newRow = newRow.replace('<!-- <', '<!-- ');
    $("#tbl tr:last").after(newRow);    
});
```

where the newRow is actually the data returned by your server call.

Comment: It would work but my UI could break after the server side modifications even if server produces valid html

Answer (score 0):

if you get always string like that and you don't want to have comment at all, you can strip it off

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    var responseString = "<!-- <abc --><tr><td>New</td></tr>";
    var index = responseString.indexOf("-->")+3;
    var formatedString = responseString.slice(index);
    $("#tbl tr:last").after(formatedString);  
});
```